How to disable deprecated messages in Laravel
I encountered deprecated errors in my application and don't know how to disable it in Laravel.

Deprecated: Carbon\Traits\Date :: getDaysFromStartOfWeek(): Implicitly marking parameter $weekStartsAt as nullable is deprecated, the explicit nullable type must be used instead in
C:\laragon\www\laravel-c45\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Date.php on line 1394
Deprecated: Carbon\Traits\Date :: setDaysFromStartOfWeek(): Implicitly marking parameter $weekStartsAt as nullable is deprecated, the explicit nullable type must be used instead in
C:\laragon\www\laravel-c45\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Date.php on line 1412
Deprecated: Carbon\Traits\Date :: utcOffset(): Implicitly marking parameter $minuteOffset as nullable is deprecated, the explicit nullable type must be used instead in C:\laragon\www\laravel-
c45\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Date.php on line 1481
...
Image: Deprecated messages in Laravel application

Currently, I'm working on Laravel project, and this project have been untouched for a week or two. In the meantime, I worked on another project and upgraded my PHP version. Now, when I'm back into this project again, these errors are displayed in the application, and I want to disable the logging in this project. If you have a way to disable the logging in Laravel, please let me know.

What version of Laravel are you using? If you are still on 10.x, make sure you upgrade to v10.48.25, which has fixes for PHP 8.4.

Laravel Framework 10.48.25

Recently, I tried to downgrade my PHP in Laragon and in Composer path, now the app works fine now. Instead of displaying errors in the webpage, the error now comes up when I try to see my laravel version php artisan --version--to put it simply, it comes up when I use php artisan commands.

This looks like a Carbon issue rather than a Laravel issue. If you have an explicit dependency of Carbon in your composer.json try removing that and also try running a composer update to get the latest carbon version which does seem to be using explicitly nullable types

Already tried that too. Yet, it still displays errors
